# thread access shared variables after main thread exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, detach

What would happen in a multi-thread C++ program if a detached thread accesses shared variables(e.g. global variable) after the call thread exits and destruct the shared variable?

```
class A {
 public:
  A() { printf("Constructing A\n"); }
  ~A() { printf("Destructing A\n"); }
  void printSomething() { printf("A is printing\n"); }
}

A a;

void thread_func() {
  printf("begin thread.\n");
  sleep(3); // make sure main thread exit first
  a.printSomething();
  printf("ending thread");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::thread t(thread_func);
  t.detach();

  return 0;
}
```

The program produces:

```
bash$ ./a.out
Constructing A
Destructing A
bash$
```

It seems main thread created global variable a and destroy it when exiting. Then what would happen after 3 seconds if the detached child thread tries to access this global variable?

And another confusion is, why does main thread clear up all resources when it exits? Looks like the lifetime of global variable is only dependent on main thread?

Comment: When main thread exits, it's going to destruct t as well. Use fork if you want something to outlive main.

Comment: Where are the `printf()` statements from the threaded function?

Comment: The printf() statement does not output in shell every time. Sometimes it has "begin thread" printed out. I think it depends on scheduling order of two threads.

Answer (score 1):

Processes exit when `main()` returns, or any thread calls `exit()` or `_exit()`.

However, `main()` can call `pthread_exit()` - and that will **not** terminate the process.  Per the Linux [`pthread_exit()` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_exit):

> When a thread terminates, process-shared resources (e.g., mutexes,
>   condition variables, semaphores, and file descriptors) are not
>   released, and functions registered using atexit(3) are not called.
>
> After the last thread in a process terminates, the process terminates
>   as by calling exit(3) with an exit status of zero; thus,
>   process-shared resources are released and functions registered using
>   atexit(3) are called.

Answer (score 0):

Threads do not have their own memory per-se, but share memory with their parent process. They are tied to their parent; therefore, whenever the parent dies, it's child threads are also killed off.

Comment: Even if the child is detached, it will also be killed off when main thread exit?

Comment: So detaching a thread doesn't remove its dependency from its parent. When you detach a thread, its parent no longer has to kill it off to clean up the resources. Detached threads, once they exit, will automatically clean up their memory, instead of requiring the parent to `pthread_join` them. Threads, by definition, can't survive as their own entity. They MUST be a part of a process.